# Copy selected file to directory in python

Tags: python, tkinter, shutil

Im trying to copy a file which is selected using a dialog window to a relative directory.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from shutil import copy2
import os


root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
source = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=(("HTML Files","*.html"), ("all files", "*.*")))
target = '/import'
print("Selected file " + source)
copy2(source, target)
```

After selecting a file, it won't appear in the target directory.

Edit: Added a second file dialog to select the target directory, now it works.

```
from tkinter import filedialog 
from tkinter import *
from shutil import copy2
import time


root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.source = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select source file",filetypes = (("html files",".html"),("all files",".*"))) 
print ("Selected file " + root.source)
time.sleep(1)
root.target = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = "/",title = "Select target directory")
print ("Selected directory " + root.target)
copy2(root.source, root.target, follow_symlinks=True)
```

Comment: Instead of using askopenfilename(), you can't use asksavefilename() method?

   
    root.filename =  filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))

Answer (score 0):

You should just check out the documentation more carefully. Your target should be a complete file directory, not just the `'import'` string. On your example, this should look like this:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from shutil import copy2
import os

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

source = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=(("HTML Files","*.html"), ("all files", "*.*")))

target = 'import'
dir_parts = list(os.path.split(source))
target_dir = dir_parts[0] + target + '/' + dir_parts[1]

copy2(source, target_dir)
```

Comment: doesnt work either, now i only get     FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: xxxxx

Comment: Maybe you don't have the import folder in the directory? This code works fine for me.

Comment: Just confirmed that copy2 won't work if there is no import folder. Got the same error as you did.

Comment: i found a working solution, edited the original question. thanks for the help though.

Comment: Glad you could figure that out!